# GUIMiner stuck at 99% Done for over 1 hour

Tags: client, guiminer

I have just started up my client *GUIMiner* for the first time.  It was downloading the block chain without any issue and got up to 99% where it has been stuck for the past 1 to 1.5 hours.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: No, it is not normal.  Which client, and what version?  Can you try shutting it down and restarting the app?

Comment: Gotta love it when a port is blocked. I was using GUIMine which ought to add some connection timeout stuff.

Comment: @SouthFresh So, is this fixed?

Comment: If it is fixed, you should answer your own question. If not, you should post more here so we can try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network issues were preventing this from completing.

Comment: I'll upvote if you add some more details so that it can help future readers.

Comment: I'm not sure I remember the blocked port. It's been a while. I"ll check through my settings.

Comment: Well, as of now the answer doesn't even say anything about a blocked port. "Network issues" could be anything.